# $(this).attr does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

With alert debug, the branch of if was executed. But the code tag that matched did not get the "data-language" attribute.

```
divs.html(function (index, oldhtml) {
    var newhtml = converter.makeHtml(oldhtml);
    var pat = /\{-# CODE (.+?) #-}/i;
    $('code', newhtml).text(function (index, text) {
        var m = text.split("\n")[0].match(pat);
        if (m) {
            $(this).attr("data-language", m[1]);
        }
    });
    return newhtml;
});
```

Comment: Did you check what the value of `m[1]` is?

Comment: It is because you are not modifying `newhtml` string with the attribute, you are creating a dom copy of `newhtml` and modifying it, those changes are not brought back to `newhtml` hence it is not working

Comment: @Juhana : Yes. With test text, I got in the branch of if (m) .

Comment: @ArunRJohny : I suspected that. But I do not know how fix that....

Answer (score 0):

> But the code tag that matched did not get the "data-language" attribute.

That's because you're not getting the "data-language" attribute, you're **setting** it.

```
$(this).attr("data-language", m[1]);
```

This *sets* the "data-language" attribute to whatever is stored in `m[1]`. Please refer to jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) documentation.

To *get* the data from the element, you'd use either:

```
$(this).attr('data-language');
```

Or (more semantically correct):

```
$(this).data('language');
```

---

To set data attributes, you should again make use of jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method:

```
$(this).data('language', m[1]);
```

Comment: I think by "the code tag that matched did not get the "data-language" attribute." they mean the attribute isn't set on that element.